# Running grep for a string with non-rendering characters

Tags: grep, regular-expression, character-encoding

So I have a log.txt files which I can search in Notepad++ on Windows, however due to the sheer number of them, I'd like to be able to run grep on them. However, the data is formatted with non-rendering characters which I don't know how to include in my grep. Notepad++ shows them as the black RS. The format of the data is like `[RS]value1[RS]value2` and I need to be able to grep for value1 AND value2. This format is always constant throughout these files.

How can I make grep search for this? Is there some form of escape sequence I can use? Or should I just make it search for `value1` and `value2` and completely ignore the presence of this non-rendering character?

Comment: Can you please give an example input and the *exact* desired output? Is the data always like: `[RS]value1[RS]value2`?

Comment: Yeah it's always this format. The log is like Connection[RS]name[RS], so i wish for grep to return every line which has connection[RS]name[RS] on it.If i grep just for name i get a myriad of irrelevant results.

Comment: Then just `grep "\[RS\]value1\[RS\]value2" file` should do the job

Comment: The problem is the [RS]  is what notepad++ sees it as, this charicter is actually a non-rendering record seperator, so i don't know how to pass it to grep. puu.sh/kMaVv/a90450e163.png this screenshot is of the charicter i am meaning.

Comment: probably `'.value1.value2'` or `$'\1evalue1\x1evalue2'` will work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [RS] = [image: Record Separator[1]] is a *Record Separator* character ASCII 30 0x1E

You can use this knowledge to `grep` for `$'\x1e'` (as suggested in comments) or if you want to be more general then use a character class like `[^[:print:]]` or `[[:cntrl:]]` to match it.